# How to detect product quantity change using observer in Magento 2.4.1?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, cataloginventory

We are using Magento 2.4.1 and we want to update the values of some custom attributes in the product whenever the product quantity is changed in the admin. Which events can be used to detect the quantity change?

One more question. If incase we create an observer event to change custom attribute values based on quantity changes then will the salable quantity/Magento's default MSI modules affect those custom observer events in any way?